# Set TimeZone for MySQLi insert Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I want set my custom timezone for insert record. I have tried set timezone like below but its not setting my custom timezone instead its setting server timezone for NOW(). I do not understood why its happening. Let me know if someone can help me for it.

```
<?php
function storeMessage($contact, $message, $reply) {
require("includes/conf.php");
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$contact = '+'. $contact;
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO messages (number, message, reply, time) VALUES(?, ?, ?, NOW())");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $contact, $message, $reply);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
 }
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: The NOW() function returns the current date and time. And of-course current date time of that server where you execute . because its always take input from system, so your 1st change you mysql server settings to your customer timezone then it will automatically return that time zone current date time

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin I am on shard hosting and so can not change server timezone. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The MySQL depends on the timezone that is used by the server that is hosted there, one common solution is to store your time in GMT format then on your code add the appropriate timezone offset to your records.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed it like below and its working fine.

```
<?php
function storeMessage($contact, $message, $reply) {
require("includes/conf.php");
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$time = date('Y/m/d H:i:s', time());
echo $time;
$contact = '+'. $contact;
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO messages (number, message, reply, time) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $contact, $message, $reply, $time);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
 }
?>
```

Thanks